# XAML code re-use (boolean to image binding)

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I'd like to be able to reuse this XAML rather than making a copy and changing the binding path. What's the solution for this?

I'm want to display a tick or cross for a boolean column in a data grid.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/cross.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/check.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
   </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the binding source property-name varies**, make a `UserControl` or `CustomControl` [or as **commanderz** wrote, a `ValueConverter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508496/xaml-code-re-use-boolean-to-image-binding/3509796#3509796) .

The following example shows how to create a UserControl:

```
<UserControl ..... />
  <Image> 
    <Image.Style> 
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}"> 
            <Style.Triggers> 
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="False"> 
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/cross.png"/> 
                </DataTrigger> 
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="True"> 
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/check.png"/> 
                </DataTrigger> 
            </Style.Triggers> 
        </Style> 
   </Image.Style> 
  </Image> 
</UserControl>
```

In the code behind, create a dependency-property Status.

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl {

    public bool Status {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Status", typeof(bool), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    public MyUserControl() {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }
}
```

Then you can use the user-control anyway and just bind to the status-property:

```
<local:MyUserControl Status="{Binding Status}"/>
<local:MyUserControl Status="{Binding AnotherNamedStatusProperty}"/>
```

**If the name of the binding-property is always the same**, declare the style more global and set it then for each Image you want. E.g. put the style in the `Window.Resources`-section  and define a key for it (e.g. `YourStyleKey_Style`);

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="YourStyleKey_Style"> 
        <Style.Triggers> 
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="False"> 
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/cross.png"/> 
            </DataTrigger> 
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="True"> 
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/check.png"/> 
            </DataTrigger> 
        </Style.Triggers> 
     </Style> 
  </Window.Resources>
```

In your xaml where you need such an image, declare an image and set the Style through the `Style`-attribute.

```
  <Image Style="{StaticResource YourStyleKey_Style}"
```

Comment: Thanks HCL. UserControl is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple Bool to ImageSource converter, whiich would return the "false.png", if the converted value is false and the other image if the value is true.